# Python Invalid Else Placement (Beginner)

Tags: python, if-statement

I'm getting a syntax error after an else statment. Is it due to indentation?

```
    if choice == 2:
        actor = input('Enter actor:')
        actorLower = actor.lower()
        for name in actors:
            nameLower = name.lower()
            if actorLower in nameLower:
                print(actors[name])
        else:
            print('Actor not found')
    elif choice == 1:
        movie = input('Enter movie:')
        print(moviedict[movie])
        else:  #**This is where I'm getting the syntax error**
            print('Movie not found')

    elif choice != 0:
            print('Invalid choice')
                       query('movies.txt')
```

Comment: I didn't indent your code because that might be the problem. What error do you get?

Comment: It's not the full code, is it?

Comment: I'm getting an invalid syntax error.

Comment: Is this the whole code?

Comment: 1. Show your full code. 2. Consider why you might be getting a syntax error - where is the error pointing?

Comment: You need to show us the complete `if` block. And you should post the full error message, starting from the `Traceback (most recent call last):`. Put it in a code block to preserve formatting.

Comment: No but this section contains the error.

Comment: If you don't show us the complete `if` block then we can't tell you how to fix the error. And your question will be put on hold until you fix it up so that it becomes answerable.

Comment: I included the whole if statement, I'll keep that in mind for future reference

Comment: @DonkeyKong full code is not always preferred. See [this](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: @JosephFarah Within reason. Starting your code block with an `else` statement when you're getting a syntax error is complete nonsense, no need to be pedantic.

Comment: @DonkeyKong I see what you are saying. Sorry for sounding [pedantic](http://cdn.meme.am/instances/57669382.jpg).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In plain english, `else` means **otherwise**, so you have to specify a condition of validity (the `if` key word) and a case when this `if` is not met (that is your `else`)

From your example on the second block:

```
elif choice == 1:
    movie = input('Enter movie:')
    print(moviedict[movie])
    else:
        print('Movie not found')
```

is not valid because

```
else:
    print('Movie not found')
```

does not have a if, you never test if the movie belongs to the dictionnary. A solution to that would be:

```
movie = input("Enter movie:")
if movie in moviedict.keys():
    print(moviedict[movie])
else:
    print('Movie not found')
```

Would be a solution in that case. Same thing for your first "Actor not found"

Comment: Thank you that fixed the problem

Answer (score 0):

The error occurs here

```
elif choice == 1:
        movie = input('Enter movie:')
        print(moviedict[movie])
        else:
            print('Movie not found')
```

You have added an `else` statement without an `if`. That is the reason it says invalid `else` placement. Either add a `if` before the `else` or remove the else part.